Amazon thermostat not connecting to wifi
I have an Amazon Smart Thermostat and it will not connect to my WiFi. I have verified this by checking my router's app and seeing that the thermostat is not connected.
I have preformed a factory reset and while that works, it only works for a minute. I have bought a second one, only for the same issue. I have checked the wiring, all is correct. I have disabled my custom DNS+DHCP server (pi-hole) and used my router's (Google WiFi) built in DHCP and DNS only for it to not work. I have put one of the mesh units right next to the thermostat only for it to have no effect. The unit works as a thermostat, but a red light is always displayed to show that there is an error (no connectivity in this case). I have also tried resetting it and using my mobile hotspot to connect it.

what is your question?

How to connect the IoT device (The Amazon Thermostat) to the wifi and get it to stay connected

Using your router's user interface, create a 2.4GHz only network and try connecting to it with the thermostat.

Google Wifi doesn't let me make a 2.4GHz only network
